# c++ 2d array passing into a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, g++

I am trying to develop a code for my thesis and for that I was trying to learn how to pass a 2D array to a function. I wrote something. The code is in the below and it is not working in this form. I am having this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘float (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)n) + -1)) + 1)]’ to ‘float (*)[2]’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘void func(int, int, float (*)[2], float)’
  func(m, n, a, omega);
```

When I change this matrix declaration float a[m][n]; to float a[2][2] it is working. Thank you in advance.

```
    void func(int m1, int n1, float a1[2][2], float omeg);

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int m = 2;
    int n = 2;
    int i, j;
    float a[m][n];
    float x,y,z,omega, c;
    x=0.1;
    y=0.2;
    z=0.3;
    c = 0;
    omega = (x*y*z)/x;

    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
        a[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    func(m, n, a, omega);

    cout << a[1][0] << endl;

return 0;
}

void func(int m1, int n1, float a1[][2], float omeg)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n1; j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < m1; i++)
            {   
            a1[i][j] = omeg * 5;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Use `const` for `m` and `n`, else you use non standard extension variable length array(VLA).

Comment: Why not using  vector (www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of array?

Comment: I'm not even try to post an answer, you are trying to use C++ w/o any knowledge about pointers and parameters passing. You need to learn those before writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `const` for `m` and `n`, else you use a non-standard extension variable length array(VLA).

I suggest to use `std::array` which is more intuitive (or `std::vector` if size is dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the declaration

```
float a[m][n]
```

is not possible. It is impossible to specify variable or constant array sizes this way. The declaration as

```
float a[2][2]
```

is nicer to read if the size is actually 2 by 2, but internally it is the same as if the declaration

```
float (*a)[2]
```

is used. For C arrays, it it impossible to know the size after definition of the array and declaration of an array of fixed size as a parameter is impossible, at least not with the desired effect.

Comment: That's not right - `float a[2][2]` as a parameter type is equivalent to `float (*a)[2]`, not `float** a`. Because of this, you can only omit the first dimension size: `float a[][2]`.

Comment: I was mistaken and have corrected my answer; but what exactly is the consequence? To my understanding, this still does not enforce checking of bounds or give any other information that would prevent undesired usage, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
int main(){

     int i, j;
     float a[2][2];
     float x,y,z,omega, c;
     x=0.1;
     y=0.2;
     z=0.3;
     c = 0;
     omega = (x*y*z)/x;

     for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
     {
       for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
         {
           a[i][j] = 0.0;
         }
     }
     func(a, omega);

     cout << a[1][0] << endl;

     return 0;
   }

   void func(float a1[2][2], float omeg)
   {
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
     {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {   
        a1[i][j] = omeg * 5;
        }
    }
   }
```